# Unix replace a particular type of string in file through unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have a situation that I need to replace a particular type of string in a file.

Scenario is:

user input like this:

```
abc = 21
xyz=32;34;35
```

The user can input many numbers in xyz but format should be  ";" separated values
Now I need to replace these values in a particular file suppose test.txt

This file has a format like this:
test.txt

```
cond0=abc
cond1=xyz
Cond2=abcxyz%
```

hence output should be like this

```
cond0=21
cond1=32;34;35
cond2=2132%;2134%;2135%
```

I am using below command to do this  but from this I am not able to get right output in cond2

```
sed "s/abc/${abc}/g" "$TEST_DIR/$file" > "$TEST_DIR/$file.bak" && mv "$TEST_DIR/$file.bak" "$TEST_DIR/$file"

sed "s/xyz/${xyz}/g" "$TEST_DIR/$file" > "$TEST_DIR/$file.bak" && mv "$TEST_DIR/$file.bak" "$TEST_DIR/$file"
```

Can anyone have a look at this?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you pipe through all of your conditions?

```
sed "s/abc/$abc/g" <$TEST_DIR/$file | sed "s/xyz/$xyz/g" >$TEST_DIR/newfile
mv $TEST_DIR/newfile $TEST_DIR/$file
```

Note that you will have to make this two operations, i.e., writing to a temporary file and then renaming.  Otherwise you'll end up wiping out the file.

The input "<" and output ">" redirections are handled by the shell, and the moment they see ">somefile", the "somefile" is truncated.  So you can never do `cat <file >file` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using bash,

```
abc=21
xyz='32;34;35'
abcxyz=$(sed -r "s/^|;/\0${abc}/g;s/;|$/%\0/g" <<< "${xyz}")
sed -i~ "s/abcxyz%/${abcxyz}/;s/abc/${abc}/;s/xyz/${xyz}/" inputFile
```